# jquery drag and drop issue

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have two divs in my page, div1 contains 3 droppable images (p1,p2,p3)  and div2 contains 3 draggable images (g1,g2,g3):  each gi  can be dropped on any pi, it should stick to the top left  corner of the droppable item. If it is not dropped on a pi, it should return to its original position.  After being dropped on a pi,  gi  can be dragged again and dropped to another pi. However, each droppable can keep only one droggable at a time.

My code is:

```
    <style>
        #div1, #div2 {
            position:relative;
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
            border:3px solid black;
        }
        .drag,.drop,.over {
        position:absolute;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        }
        .drop {
            border:1px solid green;
        }
        .over { 
            border:1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function() {
    $('.drag').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper:'clone'
    });
    $('.drop').droppable({
        over: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('.drop').addClass('over');
        },
        out: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('drop');
        },
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            if ($(this).children().length > 0) return false;//each droppable just keep one draggable
            $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);//stick to the left corner of droppable
            //$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
            $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('drop');
        }
    });
   });
   $('body').append("<div id='div1'></div>");
   $('body').append("<div id='div2'></div>");
   $('#div1').append("<img id='p1'class='drop' style='width:50; height:50; top: 50px; left:50px;' src='images/1.jpg'></img>");
   $('#div1').append("<img id='p2'class='drop' style='width:50; height:50; top:250px; left:50px;' src='images/2.jpg'></img>");
   $('#div1').append("<img id='p3'class='drop' style='width:50; height:50; top:350px; left:50px;' src='images/3.jpg'></img>");

   $('#div2').append("<img id='g1'class='drag' style='width:50; height:50; top: 50px; left:50px;' src='images/11.jpg'></img>");
   $('#div2').append("<img id='g2'class='drag' style='width:50; height:50; top:250px; left:50px;' src='images/12.jpg'></img>");
   $('#div2').append("<img id='g3'class='drag' style='width:50; height:50; top:350px; left:50px;' src='images/13.jpg'></img>");
});

</script>
```

My problem: when I drop a gi on a pi, the gi is disappeared (and therefore, I cannot drag and drop it on another item, It does not stick to the left corner of the corresponding pi). How can I prevent it from being disappeared? And stick it to droppable object?

(If I remove “$(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);” and “helper:clone”, gi does not disappear after being dropped, but it can move freely.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem by converting

```
 $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
```

to

```
$(ui.draggable).detach().appendTo('#div1').css({top: $(this).position().top,left: $(this).position().left,width:30,height:30});
```

Thanks.